# SQL Trigger Creation - How do I check if NULL or empty?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

I'm having some issues with my SQL syntax it seems.
I'm trying to create a trigger and then check if data is NULL or empty.

This is the code now thanks to Bill & Gordon:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tablename_OnInsert`;

    DELIMITER $$

    CREATE TRIGGER `tablename_OnInsert` BEFORE INSERT ON `users`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.`swid` IS NULL OR NEW.`swid` = '' THEN
            SET NEW.`swid` = CONCAT('{', uuid(), '}');
        END IF
    END$$
    ;
```

The server *still* responds with an 1064:

```
/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 7 */
```

I've been looking around to see what I am doing wrong here, but I just don't get it.

Comment: There is an unpaired/orphan `)`. An expression group was probably supposed to be opened after the `IF`, as in: `IF (..expr here..)`; alternatively, the `)` can be simply omitted.

Comment: For the null part you can use `COALESCE(value_1, value_2, etc.)`, it will return the first value that is not null

Comment: You need a `;` after `END IF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tablename_OnInsert`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `tablename_OnInsert` BEFORE INSERT ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.`swid` IS NULL OR NEW.`swid` = '' THEN
        SET NEW.`swid` = CONCAT('{', uuid(), '}');
    END IF;
END$$
```

Your problem appears to be the extra `)` in the `IF`.  However, I recommend `BEGIN`/`END` and setting the delimiter.

Comment: This needs a `;` after `END IF`